# erlang_protobuffs doesn't decode as expected for messages with repeated field

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers

I am working on a project that uses google proto buffers for internal data exchanges. It works fine as advertised, however it doesn't works as expected for messages with repeated fields in them. Here is an example:

Sample `test.proto` file:

```
message Test {
    optional string t = 1;
}

message Tests {
    repeated Test testsList = 1;
}
```

Generate erlang code:

```
1> protobuffs_compile:scan_file("test.proto").
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Sep-2012::16:38:25 ===
Writing header file to "test_pb.hrl"

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Sep-2012::16:38:25 ===
Writing beam file to "test_pb.beam"
ok
```

Generated `test_pb.hrl`:

```
-ifndef(TEST_PB_H).
-define(TEST_PB_H, true).
-record(test, {
    t
}).
-endif.

-ifndef(TESTS_PB_H).
-define(TESTS_PB_H, true).
-record(tests, {
    testslist = []
}).
-endif.
```

Encode:

```
5> test_pb:encode_tests({tests, [{test, <<"t">>}]}).
<<10,3,10,1,116>>
```

Decode:

```
6> test_pb:decode_tests(<<10,3,10,1,116>>).
{[{test,"t"}],undefined}
```

As in the above example, decoding doesn't give back the expected record tuple:

```
{tests, [{test, <<"t">>}]}
```

Has someone faced a similar issue before? Where am I missing the trick?
Any pointers and help will be greatly appreciated.

For versioning info, deps line from my rebar.config:

```
{protobuffs, "0.7.0", {git, "git://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs.git", {tag, "0.7.0"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for an update.

`0.7.0`, `0.6.0` and `HEAD` were all giving me the same problem as described above.

After discussion on #riak IRC, I realized we need to use stable release marked by this commit hash: `e0f5f6ea4c3dcb4e7b824496d2b48333fbd5a8c8` which solves the above issue.

Comment: Just for update for users reading this, Basho guys have already fixed it. So it's fine to use master now: https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs/pull/32